# Javascript: Proper closure syntax and formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am only moderately experienced with JS/jQuery. I am attempting to parse an XML object that I retrieved from IIS, here's some pseudocode that roughly describes my problem:

```
    //accepts an XML Object
    function dataFromAjax(object) {
        var x; // this is an int used to ID the object
        var y;
        var z;
        var arr = [];
        var __data = this;
        var xmlObject = object;

        function readDataFromXMLObject() {
           __data.x = $(xmlObject).find("X").text();
           __data.y = $(xmlObject).find("Y").text();
           __data.z = $(xmlObject).find("Z").text();

           testArr = $(xmlObject).find("TestArrInfo").text().split(",");

           if(testArr[0] != null)
              __data.arr.push(testArr[0]);
           // ...
        }

        function storeData() {
            sessionStorage.setItem(__data.x, JSON.stringify(__data));
        }

        readDataFromXMLObject();
        storeData();
    }
```

In the console it gives me the following error while attempting to parse arr[]:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

When I try manually typing something like `sessionStorage.getItem(123)` (with and without quotes) it also returns null.

To test the values, I tried both `console.log(xmlObject)` and `console.log(__data.x)` for debugging, those worked fine and gave me the XML object and value of x, respectively. Not sure why the array isn't working or why the whole object doesn't save. I'd greatly appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scope you can access to `arr` directly:

```
arr.push(testArr[0])
```

Your `this` context probably points to `window` object. `window.arr` is undefined.

Read about `this` context in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Thanks! I assumed that they had to be accessed via __data as console.log(x) was undefined, but console.log(__data.x) returned the value. I still need to figure out how context works with regards to closures.